# Save to database on click of button

Tags: php, html, database, model

I have a page with several models it.

If the user changes something in a texbox within the modal, is there a way it can save the changes on click without going to a new page?

Here is an example model:

```
<div id="myModal6" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                    <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Homepage Testimonial</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                               <h5><b>Testimonial: </b></h5>
              <textarea name="hometest" style="width: 500%" height:"150%";><?php echo $hometest ; ?>  </textarea>
              <br><br>

              <h5><b>Testimonial From:</b> </h5><input type="text" name="hometestfrom" value="<?php echo $hometestfrom ; ?>"><br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn red" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                                <a href='index.php'>    <button class="btn green">Save</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Yup you can use **[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** to make the call on button click.

Comment: Thanks @PatsyIssa - Any further help?

Comment: @Shane thing is i could write you a snippet to do it, but would i have really helped you? Give ajax a shot and if you're stuck somewhere don't be afraid to ask on SO we ll jump to the rescue.

Comment: @PatsyIssa ok, I have looked at ajax and found `$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt",success:function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
});` Just not sure what to do with it ha! Apologies for my stupidity

Comment: Give your save button an id, and attach the listener to it, like so $('#mysavebutton').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault;
});

Comment: Of course you need to include jquery.js first. Read the jquery documentation, particularly the Ajax parts. Then add jquery to your page (load it in a `script` tag; I hope you know how to do that), then start applying the stuff you find in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Make a callable php function somewhere:

```
function saveToDB() { 
  // save logic here, handle data from $_POST array  
}
```

In your modal window add a onclick="saveDataInDB()" to the Button

`<button class="btn green" onclick="saveDataInDB()">Save</button>`

then add a javascript that posts your required data to the php script

```
<script>
function saveDataInDB() {
    $.post('urlofphpscripthere',{'somedata': 'somethingfromyourform'},function(){ 
      // callback function, you could eg close your window if everything was saved successfully 
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: i dont unserstand? Sorry??

Comment: lets say you have a save.php file.
in this file you take data posted to it and save it to the database with php

then your buttonclick triggers a post to that file containing the data you want to save in your database, with a call like:
`<script>
$.post('http://www.yourdomain.com/save.php',{'filename': 'hello.txt', 'fileId': 1},function(data){ alert('saved successfully'); });
</script>`

Comment: In the save.php file you would now do something like this:

`$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
$fileId = $_POST['fileId];`

and then use whatever you use to save that information into your database (like a mysql command or something provided by the framework you are using)
send a response to the callback function for example with echo "success";

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to solve the problem..
put another class for your button

```
<button class="btn green submit">Save</button>
```

then use Jquery ajax call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.submit').click(function() {
       $.ajax({        
          type:"POST",
          url:"<?php echo 'urPhpFile/urFunction' ?>",
          data:{data u wanna pass},
          dataType:"json", //better to use json encode
          success:function(data)
          {
               //do sth after data returned
          }
          error:function(e)
          {
                // do sth else
          }
        });
   });
});
</script>
```